# Eurostat import data giving UnboundLocalError: local variable 'raw_part_data' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, dataframe, api

I am trying to get data from Eurostat via the eurostat python package ([info here](https://pypi.org/project/eurostat/)).

I am using the following code

```
import eurostat
df = eurostat.get_data_df('MIGR_ASYPENCTZM')
```

The data I am trying to get is from [this page](https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/databrowser/view/MIGR_ASYPENCTZM/default/table?lang=en)

It is returning the following error:

```
MIGR_ASYPENCTZM not found in the Eurostat server
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnboundLocalError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-9520b9c4f8bf> in <module>()
----> 1 df = eurostat.get_data_df('MIGR_ASYPENCTZM')

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/eurostat/eurostat.py in get_data(code, flags)
     77     except Exception:
     78         print("{0} not found in the Eurostat server".format(code))
---> 79     raw_part_data[2] = sub(r"\t", ",", raw_part_data[2])
     80     n_text_fields = raw_part_data[0].count(",") + 1
     81     if flags == True:

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'raw_part_data' referenced before assignment
```

Any help is much appreciated :)

Comment: I recommend to ask here: https://bitbucket.org/noemicazzaniga/eurostat/issues?status=new&status=open

Answer (score 0):

Try putting everything in lower case:

```
df = eurostat.get_data_df('migr_asypenctzm')
```